# LINE by naver api for android

Tags: android, api

I checked this [Is there an API for Line by Naver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494444/is-there-an-api-for-line-by-naver)
But there is no solution for android.

How about the solution for android now? 
How can we made a one click posting message to LINE sns from an android app?
Hope there are some help. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same boat looking for a solution for my iOS app and managed to get it working from the limited info they have on their ["Line for Media Operators" site](http://media.line.me/howto/en/). Look under the 'Technical Specifications' Format 2.

To post a message directly to the LINE app (check it's installed first) you just need to send a url request from within your code with the following format:

```
line://msg/text/(your message string here)
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Can you post with one click, or you have to click some more button after LINE app run?

Comment: Not at this stage. It switches to the LINE app, user is presented with the post view and the message string from your app is shown. The user reviews the msg and clicks done.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, but if we can implement by one click and get responding, that's better

Comment: No worries. Yes, I totally agree. It's pretty basic but here's hoping they improve it as time goes on.

Comment: @Tom Hoping you can mark this as the accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: I'm really want to do that, but i'm finding for "one click" posting, I appreciate your help.

Comment: That makes sense but since that's not made possible by LINE at present the answer I've given is the only solution.

Comment: OK, let wait for a week more, can you?